# Programatically change state of GridViewCheckBoxColumn row with updating binding source for Telerik's GridView

Tags: wpf, binding, telerik, behavior, radgridview

I'm making a custom behavior for Telerik's RadGridView.
When this behavior is attached and its `PropertyName` is set to same property as specified by 
DataMemberBinding value of some of the GridViewCheckBoxColumn of the grid, then toggling the checkbox in that column will apply same checkbox state to all selected rows (but only to the same column).

That happens in the `ApplyToAllSelected` method, namely in `gvcb.SetCurrentValue(GridViewCheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, isChecked);` line. The visuals are working as expected, and all checkbox values are updated on screen.

**The Problem** is that the binding source is not updated for those rows. Only for the one where click happened. `GridViewCheckBox.IsChecked` dependency property does not seem to be bound directly to the datacontext's property, so `gvcb.GetBindingExpression(GridViewCheckBox.IsChecked)` returns `null`.

**The Question**: how to update source after setting checkbox state?

```
public sealed class CheckAllSelectedBehavior : Behavior<RadGridView>
    {
        public event EventHandler Toggled;

        public string PropertyName { get; set; }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            this.AssociatedObject.PreparingCellForEdit += this.AssociatedObject_PreparedCellForEdit;
            this.AssociatedObject.CellEditEnded += this.AssociatedObject_CellEditEnded;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.PreparingCellForEdit -= this.AssociatedObject_PreparedCellForEdit;
            this.AssociatedObject.CellEditEnded -= this.AssociatedObject_CellEditEnded;
            base.OnDetaching();
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_CellEditEnded(object sender, GridViewCellEditEndedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cell.Column.UniqueName == this.PropertyName && e.EditingElement is CheckBox cb)
            {
                cb.Checked -= this.Cb_Checked;
                cb.Unchecked -= this.Cb_Unchecked;
            }
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_PreparedCellForEdit(object sender, GridViewPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column.UniqueName == this.PropertyName && e.EditingElement is CheckBox cb)
            {
                cb.Checked += this.Cb_Checked;
                cb.Unchecked += this.Cb_Unchecked;
            }
        }

        private void Cb_Unchecked(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ApplyToAllSelected(false);
        }

        private void Cb_Checked(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ApplyToAllSelected(true);
        }

        private void ApplyToAllSelected(bool isChecked)
        {
            foreach (var item in this.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems)
            {
                var row = this.AssociatedObject.GetRowForItem(item);
                var cell = row.GetCellFromPropertyName(this.PropertyName);
                if (cell.Content is GridViewCheckBox gvcb)
                {
                    gvcb.SetCurrentValue(GridViewCheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, isChecked);
                }
            }

            this.Toggled?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection to set the value on viewmodel property seems to work. Modify the `ApplyToAllSelected` method like follows:

```
private void ApplyToAllSelected(bool isChecked)
{
    foreach (var item in this.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems)
    {
        this.SetProperty(item, isChecked);
    }

    this.Toggled?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private void SetProperty(object target, bool isChecked)
{
    var prop = target.GetType().GetProperty(
       this.PropertyName,
       BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty);
    prop.SetValue(target, isChecked);
}
```